# Unable to install zipline and TA-lib python libs

Tags: python, libraries, ta-lib, zipline

I tried installing both of them but I am getting the error, I tried every other error post like this but this is not getting fixed.

pip install zipline
Collecting ziplineNote: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Using cached zipline-1.3.0.tar.gz (2.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=7.1.0 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zipline) (20.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>18.0 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zipline) (49.2.0.post20200714)
Collecting Logbook>=0.12.5
Using cached Logbook-1.5.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (115 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2016.4 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zipline) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.1 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zipline) (1.19.0)
Collecting requests-file>=1.4.1
Using cached requests_file-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.1 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from zipline) (1.5.0)
Collecting pandas<=0.22,>=0.18.1
Using cached pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz (11.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
**ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

```
  *command: 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt_2kyik\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Cython 'numpy==1.9.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.12.1; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.1; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"''***
       cwd: None
  Complete output (371 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
  Collecting setuptools
    Downloading setuptools-49.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (789 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)
  Collecting numpy==1.13.1
    Using cached numpy-1.13.1.zip (5.0 MB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ta_0lrux'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\
    Complete output (155 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
    Running setup.py clean for numpy
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy
    Complete output (10 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
  
    `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
  
      - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
      - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                          files that aren't checked into the git repo)
  
    Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
  
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: yfinance 0.1.54 has requirement numpy>=1.15, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: statsmodels 0.11.1 has requirement numpy>=1.14, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: seaborn 0.10.1 has requirement numpy>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: scipy 1.5.0 has requirement numpy>=1.14.5, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: scikit-learn 0.23.1 has requirement numpy>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: pywavelets 1.1.1 has requirement numpy>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: pandas 1.0.5 has requirement numpy>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: numba 0.50.1 has requirement numpy>=1.15, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: mlxtend 0.17.2 has requirement numpy>=1.16.2, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  ERROR: astropy 4.0.1.post1 has requirement numpy>=1.16, but you'll have numpy 1.13.1 which is incompatible.
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, Cython, numpy
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5u99_38u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt_2kyik\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt_2kyik\overlay\Include\numpy'
           cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\
      Complete output (160 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
  
      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
  
        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
  
  
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
          Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
          the ATLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      F2PY Version 2
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      building library "npymath" sources
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_x3y5_ls\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5u99_38u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt_2kyik\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt_2kyik\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt_2kyik\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Cython 'numpy==1.9.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.12.1; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.1; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.

enter code here
```